# ngrx error: Actions must have a type property

Tags: angular, ngrx

I'm fairly new to Angular 4/ngrx and Rx so not quite sure what i'm doing wrong here.  In my Effect I want to execute a search using my service.  The method returns an Observable.  Then I map that to return a new payload.

here is the code:

```
    @Effect() executeSearchEffect = this.actions.ofType(SEARCH_EXECUTE)
    .map((a: SearchExecuteAction) => {
        return this.searchService.doSearch(a.payload.search.searchText)
                   .map((r) => {
                        type: SEARCH_COMPLETE,
                        payload: a.payload   // just for testing,same as input!
                          }));
    });
```

In the above, doSearch returns an Observable.  The error I get is Actions must have a type property which I am returning here.

if I change the code to simply as below it works without errors like a charm:

```
    @Effect() executeSearchEffect = this.actions.ofType(SEARCH_EXECUTE)
    .map((a: SearchExecuteAction) => {
        return {
               type: SEARCH_COMPLETE,
               payload: a.payload   // just for testing,same as input!
               });
```

What am I doing wrong here, how do I map the Observable from my service to dispatch a new action.  Note, my Actions are just interfaces so I can't do a new SearchCompleteAction({}) etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your first code your aren't returning anything. Because `(e) => { }` just opens a scope and doesn't return an object. That's why your second code is working. You have to write `return` to return an object when using array functions.

Also you should really consider taking a look at the [**ngrx-example-app**](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/tree/master/projects/example-app).

Comment: Yep that will return `undefined` or if a is defined the value of `a`.

Comment: What am saying is , you said he is not returning anything , but he has a return statement in it. So just curious if I am missing anything ..

Comment: I'm talking about  why the first part is throwing the error: `(r) => {
                        type: SEARCH_COMPLETE,
                        payload: a.payload
                          }`. What does not return anything, it's actually a syntax error.

Comment: oh, ok . Thankyou. That should be `()=>({})`

Comment: Yes it should ;)

Comment: yep, that was it, the inner was missing the return, now it works.  I was confused by the syntax because without the braces you can do r => r.id for instance so I was using it with the braces like so r => {r.id, r.xyz} but I guess once you open the brace you need to return because it becomes scope of code and not an object representation.

Comment: @cyr_x your link to repo doesn't work, can you please update it. I guess they have moved the link

Answer (score 4):

Assuming `searchService` makes a http call to search , `.map` do not wait for the async call. You should use `.flatMap` .

```
  @Effect() executeSearchEffect = this.actions.ofType(SEARCH_EXECUTE)
    .flatMap((a: SearchExecuteAction) => 
        this.searchService.doSearch(a.payload.search.searchText)
                   .map((r) => ({
                        type: SEARCH_COMPLETE,
                        payload: a.payload   // just for testing,same as input!
                          })));
    );
```

Comment: This is also correct, it addresses the second problem with the code, which OP wasn't aware about i guess. (`switchMap` would be an option too, if not the preferred  one)

Comment: The above code does not work because it requires the return, otherwise it complains because it's expecting an Observable return type:

The error is:
**Argument of type '(a: SearchExecuteAction) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: Action, index: number) => ObservableInput<{}>'**

Adding the return before this.searchService fixes the compilation error but I still get the original error.

`@Effect() executeSearchEffect = this.actions.ofType(SEARCH_EXECUTE)
    .flatMap((a: SearchExecuteAction) => 
        return this.searchService.doSearch(a.payload.search...`

Comment: Thanks, I changed to using switchMap